# how can i download movies on Acer A200

Tags: video, torrents

How can i download video torrents onto an Acer A200? I've tried several apps from Google Play including Bittorrent and uTorrent. I tried PotLocker as well. I don't know what else to try. 
This is my tablet, which I'm less familiar with, so it is possible that it's operator error, but i believe it is a compatibility issue.

Answer (score 1):

Always explain what problem you are having. It is difficult to judge whether it is a compatibility issue or a bug in the apps.

Anyway,
[Flud](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.delphicoder.flud&hl=en) works well on most phones. Some alternatives are [tTorrent](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hu.tagsoft.ttorrent.lite&hl=en) and [aTorrent](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobilityflow.torrent).

Answer (score 0):

Bittorrent and uTorrent are from same company and both are useless compared to

**aTorrent**:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobilityflow.torrent

Comment: I'm using aTorrent and it's very useful and works perfectly.